# How to create swipe to start button with moving arrows

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I want to create the exactly the same swipe button like this  https://github.com/shadowfaxtech/proSwipeButton . 
I was wondering how to change the arrow of the button on user touches

I was doing this for getting swipe action.

```
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
rightSwipe.direction = .right
view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

but the thing is how to add arrows to button which change there position on user touches.

Comment: one possible way is to use background view for the button and another view on top for the arrow.

Comment: You can create a custom UIView class which has an UIImageView inside of it and use UITouch function to get and change the position of UIImageView.

Comment: You have to create custom UIVIew and another UIVIew like an arrow that one you have to create or you can add the image of an arrow after that you have to add UIPanGestureRecognizer on arrow UIView or arrow imageview and change X coordinate.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav how we can change x coordinate as per user swipe the arrow

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I have written for swiping over the button. You assign image to the image view.

```
func createSwipeButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        button.setTitle("PLACE ORDER", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 200, width: self.view.frame.size.width-20, height: 100)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swiped(_:event:)), for: .touchDragInside)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swipeEnded(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        
        let swipableView = UIImageView.init()
        swipableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: button.frame.size.height)
        swipableView.tag = 20
        swipableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.addSubview(swipableView)
    }
    
    @objc func swiped(_ sender : UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
        let swipableView = sender.viewWithTag(20)!
        let centerPosition = location(event: event, subView: swipableView, superView: sender,isSwiping: true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            swipableView.center = centerPosition
        }
    }
    
    @objc func swipeEnded(_ sender : UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
        let swipableView = sender.viewWithTag(20)!
        let centerPosition = location(event: event, subView: swipableView, superView: sender, isSwiping: false)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            swipableView.center = centerPosition
        }) { _ in
           let halfScreenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
           if centerPosition.x > halfScreenWidth {
            print("button pressed action")
           }
        }
    }
    
    func location(event: UIEvent, subView: UIView, superView: UIButton, isSwiping: Bool) -> CGPoint {
        if let touch = event.touches(for: superView)?.first{
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocation(in: superView)
            let location = touch.location(in: superView)
            let delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
            print(subView.center.x + delta_x)
            var centerPosition = CGPoint.init(x: subView.center.x + delta_x, y: subView.center.y)
            let minX = subView.frame.size.width/2
            let maxX = superView.frame.size.width - subView.frame.size.width/2
            centerPosition.x = centerPosition.x < minX ? minX : centerPosition.x
            centerPosition.x = centerPosition.x > maxX ? maxX : centerPosition.x
            if !isSwiping{
                let normalPosition = superView.frame.size.width * 0.5
                centerPosition.x = centerPosition.x > normalPosition ? maxX : minX
                centerPosition.x = centerPosition.x <= normalPosition ? minX : centerPosition.x
            }
            return centerPosition
        }
        return CGPoint.zero
    }
```

[image]

**Complete project is on github: https://github.com/IamSaurav/SwipeButton**

Answer (score 0):

Mmm what about something like this?
You can add an UIImage in the storyboard in the swipeImage var.
The best effect is done if the image has the same color of the text.

import UIKit

```
@IBDesignable
class UISwipeableLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var swipeImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            configureSwipeImage()
        }
    }

    private var swipeImageView: UIImageView?
    private var rightSwipe: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
    private var shouldActivateButton = true

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureSwipeImage()
         clipsToBounds = true
    }
}

private extension UISwipeableLabel {

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let centerX = swipeImageView?.center.x {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self)
            let percent = centerX/frame.width

             if sender.state == .changed {
                if centerX < frame.width - frame.height/2 {
                    swipeImageView?.center.x = centerX + translation.x
                    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: swipeImageView)
                } else {
                    swipeImageView?.center.x = frame.width - frame.height/2
                    if shouldActivateButton {
                        activateButton()
                    }
                }
            }

             if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled || sender.state == .failed {
                if shouldActivateButton {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25 * TimeInterval(percent)) {
                        self.swipeImageView?.center.x = self.frame.height/2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func configureSwipeImage() {
        if swipeImageView != nil {
            swipeImageView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        swipeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.height, height: frame.height))

        if let swipeImageView = swipeImageView {
            swipeImageView.image = swipeImage
            swipeImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled =  true
             swipeImageView.alpha = 0.5
             addSubview(swipeImageView)


             rightSwipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
            if let rightSwipe = rightSwipe {
                swipeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
            }
        }
    }

    func activateButton() {
        print("*** DO YOUR STUFF HERE ***")
        }
}
```

You start with a UILabel and if you want, change it to use autolayout.